# connection_workflow.AMQPConnectorStackTimeout from BlockingConnection

Tags: python, pika, python-pika

A pika BlockingConnection attempt failed (pika version 1.0.0). The exception shown in the application log - `adapters.utils.connection_workflow.AMQPConnectorStackTimeout` - doesn't appear to be any of the exceptions in `pika.exceptions`.

Isn't pika supposed to convert internal exceptions such as this into one of those in `pika.exceptions` before surfacing it to the caller?

If not, how should I go about enumerating all the possible exceptions pika could raise so that I can decide which the caller can handle and which it should not attempt to handle? (Essentially, the caller needs to decide whether to exit on a non-recoverable exception or try again if the condition is probably transient.)

Maybe I've misinterpreted the application log, which is as follows:

```
2019-04-26T11:33:29.880310567Z ERROR:pika.adapters.utils.connection_workflow:Timeout while setting up AMQP to '█.█.█.█'/(<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, <SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM: 1>, 6, '█.█.█.█', ('█.█.█.█', ████)); ssl=False
2019-04-26T11:33:29.880880966Z ERROR:pika.adapters.utils.connection_workflow:AMQPConnector - reporting failure: AMQPConnectorAMQPHandshakeError: AMQPConnectorStackTimeout("Timeout during AMQP handshake'█.█.█.█'/(<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, <SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM: 1>, 6, '█.█.█.█', ('█.█.█.█', █)); ssl=False",)
2019-04-26T11:33:29.881053365Z ERROR:pika.adapters.utils.connection_workflow:AMQP connection workflow failed: AMQPConnectionWorkflowFailed: 1 exceptions in all; last exception - AMQPConnectorAMQPHandshakeError: AMQPConnectorStackTimeout("Timeout during AMQP handshake'█.█.█.█'/(<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, <SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM: 1>, 6, '█.█.█.█', ('█.█.█.█', ████)); ssl=False",); first exception - None.
2019-04-26T11:33:29.881150165Z ERROR:pika.adapters.utils.connection_workflow:AMQPConnectionWorkflow - reporting failure: AMQPConnectionWorkflowFailed: 1 exceptions in all; last exception - AMQPConnectorAMQPHandshakeError: AMQPConnectorStackTimeout("Timeout during AMQP handshake'█.█.█.█'/(<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, <SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM: 1>, 6, '█.█.█.█', ('█.█.█.█', ████)); ssl=False",); first exception - None
2019-04-26T11:33:29.881503064Z ERROR:pika.adapters.blocking_connection:Connection workflow failed: AMQPConnectionWorkflowFailed: 1 exceptions in all; last exception - AMQPConnectorAMQPHandshakeError: AMQPConnectorStackTimeout("Timeout during AMQP handshake'█.█.█.█'/(<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, <SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM: 1>, 6, '█.█.█.█', ('█.█.█.█', ████)); ssl=False",); first exception - None
2019-04-26T11:33:29.882705661Z ERROR:pika.adapters.blocking_connection:Error in _create_connection().
2019-04-26T11:33:29.882720061Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-04-26T11:33:29.882724561Z   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 451, in _create_connection
2019-04-26T11:33:29.882728961Z     raise self._reap_last_connection_workflow_error(error)
2019-04-26T11:33:29.882732761Z pika.adapters.utils.connection_workflow.AMQPConnectorStackTimeout: Timeout during AMQP handshake'█.█.█.█'/(<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, <SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM: 1>, 6, '█.█.█.█', ('█.█.█.█', ████)); ssl=False
2019-04-26T11:33:29.883257859Z ERROR:root:AMQPConnectorStackTimeout Timeout during AMQP handshake'█.█.█.█'/(<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, <SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM: 1>, 6, '█.█.█.█', ('█.█.█.█', ████)); ssl=False
2019-04-26T11:33:29.883273859Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-04-26T11:33:29.883278359Z   File "main.py", line 143, in <module>
2019-04-26T11:33:29.883282559Z     main()
2019-04-26T11:33:29.883286259Z   File "main.py", line 118, in main
2019-04-26T11:33:29.883290059Z     with pika.BlockingConnection(parameters=pika.URLParameters(██████████)) as connection:
2019-04-26T11:33:29.883293959Z   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 360, in __init__
2019-04-26T11:33:29.883307559Z     self._impl = self._create_connection(parameters, _impl_class)
2019-04-26T11:33:29.883311659Z   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 451, in _create_connection
2019-04-26T11:33:29.883315459Z     raise self._reap_last_connection_workflow_error(error)
2019-04-26T11:33:29.883319059Z pika.adapters.utils.connection_workflow.AMQPConnectorStackTimeout: Timeout during AMQP handshake'█.█.█.█'/(<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, <SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM: 1>, 6, '█.█.█.█', ('█.█.█.█', ████)); ssl=False
2019-04-26T11:33:29.883323159Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-04-26T11:33:29.883326759Z   File "main.py", line 143, in <module>
2019-04-26T11:33:29.883465559Z     main()
2019-04-26T11:33:29.883473059Z   File "main.py", line 118, in main
2019-04-26T11:33:29.883635558Z     with pika.BlockingConnection(parameters=pika.URLParameters(██████████)) as connection:
2019-04-26T11:33:29.883650458Z   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 360, in __init__
2019-04-26T11:33:29.883894657Z     self._impl = self._create_connection(parameters, _impl_class)
2019-04-26T11:33:29.883902657Z   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 451, in _create_connection
2019-04-26T11:33:29.884212657Z     raise self._reap_last_connection_workflow_error(error)
2019-04-26T11:33:29.884222357Z pika.adapters.utils.connection_workflow.AMQPConnectorStackTimeout: Timeout during AMQP handshake'█.█.█.█'/(<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, <SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM: 1>, 6, '█.█.█.█', ('█.█.█.█', ████)); ssl=False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem again and found my own question :-)

The documentation seems a bit lacking, but there is a whole hierarchy of exceptions in `pika.adapters.utils.connection_workflow`, the base class of which is `AMQPConnectorException`.

The answer seems to be to browse this module source to see which exceptions ought to be handled.